# Mongo DB Aggregate Query returns in Batches

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following code, :

```
CommandResult cr = db.doEval("db." + collectionName + ".aggregate("
                + query + ")");
```

Command result is giving in batches, where I need to get in single value.

```
Batch Result:{ "serverUsed" : "/servername" , "retval" : { **"_firstBatch**" : [ { "visitor_localdate" : 1367260200} , { "visitor_localdate"
```

Expected Result:

```
{ "serverUsed" : "/servername" , "retval" : { "**result**" : [ { "visitor_localdate" : 1367260200} , { "visitor_localdate"
```

The Mongo DB we are using is 2.6.4 with 64 bit.

Can any one help with this?. I am guessing there is some Configuration issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your doing this all wrong. You don't need to jump through hoops like this just to get a dynamic collection name. Just use this syntax instead:

```js
var collectionName = "collection";

var cursor = db[collectionName].aggregate( pipeline )
```

Where `pipeline` also is just the array of pipeline stage documents, ie:

```js
var pipeline = [{ "$match": { } }, { "$group": { "_id": "$field" } }];
```

At any rate the `.aggregate()` method returns a cursor, you can iterate the results with standard methods:

```js
while ( cursor.hasNext() ) {
   var doc = cursor.next();
   // do something with doc
}
```

But you are actually doing this in Java and not JavaScript, so from the base driver with a connection on object `db` you just do this:

```js
    DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject());
    DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject());

    List pipeline = new ArrayList();
    pipeline.add(match);
    pipeline.add(group);
    AggregationOutput output = db.getCollection("collectionName").aggregate(pipeline);
```

The pipeline is basically a list interface of DBObject information where you construct the BSON documents representing the operations required.

The result here is of `AggregationOutput`, but cursor like results are obtainable by additionally supplying `AggregationOptions` as an additional option to `pipeline`

Comment: Hi.. Neil , Thanks for the infor , We are trying to Achevie this in Java. Where Aggreate function dosent take pipline as Argument Directly.

Comment: @BlueWhale Sure it does. Let me fire up some code and re-tag your question.

Comment: @BlueWhale There you go, all pretty simple. You don't need to send code to the server as JavaScript to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There was something related to bacth added in mongodb 2.6, more details here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#example-aggregate-method-initial-batch-size

From the link

```
db.orders.aggregate(
[
      { $match: { status: "A" } },
      { $group: { _id: "$cust_id", total: { $sum: "$amount" } } },
      { $sort: { total: -1 } },
      { $limit: 2 }
],
      {
        cursor: { batchSize: 0 }
      }
)
```

You might be having a cursor batch in your aggregate query

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Neil Lunn is not wrong but I want to add that the result you were expecting is a result for mongodb versions earlier than v2.6.

Before v2.6, the aggregate function returned just **one document** containing a result field, which holds an array of documents returned by the pipeline, and an ok field, which holds the value 1, indicating success.
However, from mongodb v2.6 on, the aggregate function returns a **cursor** (if $out option was not used).

See [examples in mongodb v2.6 documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#examples) and compare how it worked before v2.6 (i.e. in [v2.4](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)):